# pd.read_clipboard() seg fault

Tags: python, clipboard, pandas

I cannot seem to use read_clipboard(). I have tried copying some of my data, the example data in the docs, and finally just the number 1. As you can see:

```
In [1]: %paste
1
## -- End pasted text --
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: pd.read_clipboard()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone else had trouble using this?

I use IPython 0.12.1 and the latest dev build of pandas. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
In [1]: pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.10.1'
```

And just to be safe:

```
dallan@dielectric-pc:~/pandas-danielballan$ git fetch upstream master
From git://github.com/pydata/pandas
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
dallan@dielectric-pc:~/pandas-danielballan$ git merge upstream/master
Already up-to-date.
dallan@dielectric-pc:~/pandas-danielballan$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
dallan@dielectric-pc:~/pandas-danielballan$
```

Comment: I mean the latest dev build, from github. I now see why that was very unclear.

Comment: Does 10.0.x have this problem?

Comment: That's strange, I don't see this (on Ubuntu 12.10). Have you installed via [the PPA mentioned on the website](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#binary-installers)? (Could you include pd.version.version anyway?)

Comment: See above for the version, 10.1 now. I haven't installed via the PPA. I use an installation built using ``setup.py develop`` so I can submit pull requests to pandas. Can this create weird problems? I am having this issue on an unedited clone of the master branch.

Comment: It shouldn't do, it seems to work ok from git in `'0.10.1.dev-10f255d'`...

Comment: It'd be great if you could dig down and find the line that is triggering the segfault. Please post on GitHub if you do.